# How do I set up contact and opportunity pages so that the agency field is populated based on the account field?

Tags: custom-field, dependent-picklist

I am trying to set up an agency field in both the Contact and Opportunity page layouts so that when a user fills in the account field the agency field is automatically populated based on the agency field in that account.  I would also consider some sort of lookup window dependent on the account field for selecting agency?  How can this be set up? Please provide details.  Thanks!

Comment: Tried using formula field then selected Account>Advertiser agency but this populates my agency field with a number and letter code not Text from the agency field under the account.  what needs to be changed?

Comment: Still unclear on this.  I set up a formula that insert Account>Agency but when I create a test record the agency field is not shown and is read only and instead of showing the agency based on the account I input, it has a code of numbers and letters

Answer (score 1):

If you want to populate agency field on account and Opportunity, you can do that by creating a new formula field. However If the agency field is a text field, populating the field on Opportunity and contact can be done by a workflow rule.

You will have to create a workflow rule and include a field update and choose "Use a formula to set the new value" and using Insert field in formula editor, you can accomplish that. Same goes for the opportunity.

The only caveat I see is in second approach is case when the agency is changed on account and you want it to propagate to Opportunity and Contact. In this case you will have to write a trigger.

So I will definitely recommend first approach i.e creating a formula field.